# Output multiple responses from a single Intent

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I have an Alexa Skill which I want to have an initial response to an intent, then after a delay, states another response.

I've attempted using multiple `response.tell(...)` call with a `setTimeout()` between them, but this only responds with the first `.tell()` and ends. (`.tell()` is set to end the session, but even if I set this to `false`, my code still never reaches the `setTimeout()` )

I have included some psuedo-code about what I would like to do:

```
intentHandlers.DynamicDurationIntent = function(intent, session, response) {
  var calculatedDuration = doCalculation();
  var speechDuration = convertToSpeech(calculatedDuration);
  var speechOutput = "Your duration will last <say-as interpret-as="time">' +
         speechDuration + 
         '</say-as>";
  response.tell(speechOutput); //I get this far
  setTimeout(function () {
     var speechOutputEnd = "Great job! You're done.";
     response.tell(speechOutputEnd);
  }, calculatedDuration);
}
```

An example of this model is used in the 7 Minute Workout Alexa Skill.

Is this feasible using AWS Lambda?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is not an AWS Lambda related issue, this is an Alexa related issue.

Part of the confusion seems to be the asynchronous nature of node.js making it appear that you could send multiple responses to Alexa, you can't.  The way to think about Alexa is in the same request/response type nature that a normal API call would be.  Your second response.tell has nowhere to send its data because the original request has long since concluded.

The way to think about it is Alexa is holding a conversation with the user and doesn't provide you a way to interrupt the user without them first interacting.  Your first response.tell puts the conversation back in the users hands and you can't say anything until they talk to you again.

---

All that said, there is a straightforward solution that will probably work for you available in the Alexa platform today.

You can provide a single response with SSML and put breaks in the speech output.  The [documentation for an SSML break](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/speech-synthesis-markup-language-ssml-reference#break) shows that you would look like `<break time="420s"/>` and you are already using SSML in your response.

However, for usability I would not recommend putting in a 7 minute pause.  You have alternatives such as putting in minute pauses and having encouraging speech between each minute (actually you'd want to pause for 50 something seconds probably).  Another alternative would be for you to play some time of music or workout related sound for the 7 minutes using the [audio](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/speech-synthesis-markup-language-ssml-reference#audio) SSML tag.

Comment: Very nice explanation.  "The way to think about Alexa is in the same request/response type nature that a normal API call would be."